# How to place the arrow to the right of the header of a sorted table?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, bootstrap-5, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a table and I want to add the sort option to all table headers, so I used the [bootstrap exemple](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples) for my purpose.

The only problem in this example is the position of the arrow which is on the left side and I want it on the right side of the header element.

I checked the directive code and I found the code below :

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'th[sortable]',
  standalone: true,
  host: {
    '[class.bi-caret-down-fill]': 'direction === "asc"',
    '[class.bi-caret-up-fill]': 'direction === "desc"',
    '(click)': 'rotate()',
  },
})
```

How should I change the host style to move the arrow to the right side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `index.html` css code which is handling the position is

```
....
th[sortable].desc:before,
th[sortable].asc:before {
    content: '';
    float: left;
.....
```

Change `float` property to `right` [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6cns1b?file=src%2Findex.html)

Comment: I tried but it is not working !

Comment: where did you add the CSS code? you should add it in your `style.css`. you can see it working fine in the example link

Comment: Yes I saw it and I tried first to add the code in the component css file and tried next into the style css file but not working.

Comment: please create an example stackblitz and share the link you should only need to add `th[sortable].desc:before,th[sortable].asc:before { float: left !important;` to your style.css

Comment: Sorry, I figure it out that I was putting the wrong class names. Thank you, it work fine !

Comment: is there a way to put it next to the text at the right side ? @jitender

Comment: Sry but don't have idea if that's possible or not

Comment: Thank you anyway .. you have been a great help.